# x = "189371971441827056". If I do parseInt(x) in javascript, I get 189371971441827070. Why?

Tags: javascript, parseint

If I do assign variable x = "189371971441827056" and then 
I do,

> parseInt(x)
>   189371971441827070

The value of parseInt(x) changes. I don't understand why?

Thanks in advance...!!

Comment: That number is probably larger than the largest int javascript can keep track of.

Comment: big int numbers are actually store like floating points number in javascript , so you have a rounding error inherent to the IEEE standard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = 9007199254740991

Comment: Try using BigNumber variable precision math. https://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/bignumbers.html 
There are several big number libraries out there, this one is just the first one I found.

Comment: None of them helped. How do I get an int from above value?

Comment: `BigInt(x)`,  You can't use `parseInt` because it's too big for Javascript number type.